# What does a dark colored fur mean regarding a jaguar

Tags: animal-identification

Long time ago I saw a jaguar (I believe it was one). The strange thing was, that it was extremely dark. I wouldn't refer to it as "black" but actually pretty dark.

What does such a color signal? Was it sick, young or just an optical illusion?

Comment: Where was the sighting, may help with identifying.

Comment: @AM_Hawk That was in Mexico I believe. Definitely Central America at least :)

Comment: I don't know what the color _signifies_, but there's a name for it:  "Melanism"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanism

Comment: Many big cats have colour variants caused by pigmentation. I can think of at least three; King Cheetah's (http://bit.ly/1NoIOyi), White Lions (http://bit.ly/1QGrZRb) and Black Tigers (http://bit.ly/1SieTXV). Perhaps you saw a "pigmented" Jaguar, or a Black Panther (http://bit.ly/1LQNXKK)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that what you saw was normal for a jaguar. The Panthera species (leopards [Panthera pardus] in Asia and Africa, and jaguars [Panthera onca] in the Americas) can have melanistic colours like many species. They're commonly known as Black Panthers.

Sometimes you can still see a leopard / jaguars spots through the black fur, but it's still melanistic as it's had a development of the coloured pigment melanin, other times it's a complete covering.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of that before. However, you are completely right. A quick google search confirmed your assumption.

Comment: @OddDeer It's not as commonly thought of as Albinism, but it's essentially the opposite.